# JTextField Array won't compile

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, jtextfield

I'm attempting to create a large array of JTextField objects, and for some reason my code won't compile.  I've played around with it for too long now, and I can't find any good reason for the compiler to be mad; here is my code with only a length 2 array:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class SUDOKU_temp extends JApplet
{
    //declare fields

    public JTextField[] fields = new JTextField[2];
    fields[0] = new JTextField();
    fields[1] = new JTextField();

    //other stuff happens down here that the compiler is ok with
}
```

If I only run the code with a length 1 array I get the exact same errors, which are:

```
linux63:~demo$ ./compile
SUDOKU_temp.java:11: ']' expected
    fields[0] = new JTextField();
           ^
SUDOKU_temp.java:11: ';' expected
    fields[0] = new JTextField();
            ^
SUDOKU_temp.java:11: illegal start of type
    fields[0] = new JTextField();
              ^
SUDOKU_temp.java:11: <identifier> expected
    fields[0] = new JTextField();
               ^
SUDOKU_temp.java:11: ';' expected
    fields[0] = new JTextField();
                   ^
SUDOKU_temp.java:11: illegal start of type
    fields[0] = new JTextField();
                              ^
SUDOKU_temp.java:11: <identifier> expected
    fields[0] = new JTextField();
                               ^
```

I feel like this is a problem with the compiler, and not with the code, and any help about how to debug this will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!!

Comment: This is not compilers fault at all. Its a code fault. [Eclipse Debug Tutorial](http://www.comscigate.com/debug/learn_Debug.htm)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't run code outside a method (unless it is a declaration). You need to either initialize them in some method or with an array literal.

Array literal:

```
public JTextField[] fields ={ new JTextField(),new JTextField()};
```

Within a method:

```
public JTextField[] fields=new JTextField[2];
public void method(){
    fields[0]=new JTextField();
    fields[1]=new JTextField();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  I'm a little rusty with Java, and this is a lesson I won't forget now.

Answer (score 5):

Non-declarative statements cannot be located in the class block. You need to place

```
fields[0] = new JTextField();
fields[1] = new JTextField();
```

inside a constructor, method or static initializer block. For this applet, you could use:

```
public void init() {
   for (int i=0; i < fields.length; i++ ) {
      fields[i] = new JTextField();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To add to the above, you could initialize objects in an array on declaration like so:

```
public class SUDOKU_temp {

  private JTextField[] fields = {new JTextField(), new JTextField()};
```